# Do extra empty columns affect sql table size significantly?

Tags: sql

I have a few columns that I know won't be used initially. Is it a good practice to add columns only when needed or just leave those extra columns there?

Is it just a little more space in the header or every row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on the column type to some extent.

Variable sized columns (such as `varchar(n)`) will only use 4 extra bytes (approx) per row.

I would add columns only when required, since it is less likely that redundant columns will be added and never removed.

Comment: even when they are empty? or null
my question should be does empty or null fields take up space

Comment: Yes. Empty and NULL columns do take up space. SQL Server 2008 has new row compression for sparse tables, i.e. those with lots of NULL columns...

Comment: Unless you have Huge tables, I think the maintainability issue of redundant columns is more important that space concerns. I often see DBs with may unused columns but developers are nervous to remove in case they are used somewhere else (such as export to another system etc)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they do still take up space, if only a couple bytes per row (depends on the column type). If you're not going to use them until later, what good is it to keep them there?

Answer (score 2):

I would like to add that although empty columns take up space (as mentioned in the other answers), when dealing with a big db, adding a column is not an easy task. So sometimes, it's good to have an additional column ready, even if it's just for future use.